# Modifying an image URL based on hash options

Tags: optimization, ruby, image

The code I'm trying to improve modifies a URL according to the options passed in a hash:

```
{
  :image_aspect_ratio => "square",
  :image_size => 50
}
```

or

```
{
  :image_size => {
    :width => 50,
    :height => 60
  }
}
```

The code looks like this:

```
module X
  module Y
    class Z


def image_url
  if raw_info['picture'] && image_size_opts_passed?
    image_url_with_size_opts
  else
    raw_info['picture']
  end
end

def image_size_opts_passed?
  !!(options[:image_size] || options[:image_aspect_ratio])
end

def image_url_with_size_opts
  params_index = raw_info['picture'].index('/photo.jpg')
  if params_index
    raw_info['picture'].insert(params_index, image_params)
  else
    raw_info['picture']
  end
end

def image_params
  image_params = []
  if options[:image_size].is_a?(Integer)
    image_params << "s#{options[:image_size]}"
  elsif options[:image_size].is_a?(Hash)
    image_params << "w#{options[:image_size][:width]}" if options[:image_size][:width]
    image_params << "h#{options[:image_size][:height]}" if options[:image_size][:height]
  end
  image_params << 'c' if options[:image_aspect_ratio] == 'square'

  '/' + image_params.join('-')
end
```

Here's the stuff I hate about this code:

1. Lots of `raw_info['picture']` being called, but I'm not sure if using a local variable is better than accessing a hash twice.
2. I'm seeing some duplication in the else branch in the `image_url` and `image_url_with_size_opts` methods but I don't know how to improve that.
3. This code is all inside a class which is inside a module which is inside another module, so I'm not sure if I could also memoize the `image_params` result.

Comment: What is `raw_info['picture']`? An object or just a plain array?

Comment: `raw_info` is a hash and `raw_info['picture']` is just a string.

Answer (score 2):

Overall, it's reasonably tight code. You've taken steps to reduce method size, which is good.

To answer your questions specifically:

1. I think an instance variable would be better, because then you can avoid the else clauses you mention in 2. Those methods can then be reduced to 1 or 2 lines.
2. see 1. :)
3. If you create an image or picture object, it provides a convenient place to memoize results. I'm not sure this is that important though, as it's probably not likely you'd need to generate more than one URL for a given image in a single request.

Comment: I made a mistake in my first question. I used the term "instance variable" when I meant to say "local variable". `raw_info` is already an instance variable (well, it's a method with a memoized result). And it's a hash. But since I'm accessing the same hash key so many times, should I move it to a local variable? Or should I create a memoized method to hold `raw_info['picture']`?

Comment: Also, what do you think of `if condition ... else ... end` and `return if condition ... else_branch`? Which do you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a case statement for `image_params`:

```
    def image_params
            image_params = []
            case options[:image_size]
            when Integer
               ....
            when Hash
               ....
            else
               ....
            end
            .....
    end
```

You'll recall this works because `case` uses `===`.